# \printbibliography[heading=none] also removes entry numbers

Tags: biblatex

I am trying to print my publications list on my CV. It currently looks like this in the LaTeX:

```latex
\nocite{*}
\printbibliography
```

[image]

I would like to get rid of the "References title". Adding `[heading=none]` to `\printbibliography` gives me this:

[image]

This does get rid of the heading, but also the numbering for the entries. How can I get the entry numbers back?

Update:

I am using [this](https://www.latextemplates.com/template/medium-length-professional-cv) template.

Update 2:

Here is an MWE:

blee.bib:

```
@article{leeSquiggleUserfriendlyTwodimensional2018,
  title = {Squiggle: A User-Friendly Two-Dimensional {{DNA}} Sequence Visualization Tool},
  issn = {1367-4803, 1460-2059},
  shorttitle = {Squiggle},
  doi = {10.1093/bioinformatics/bty807},
  journal = {Bioinformatics},
  author = {Lee, Benjamin D},
  editor = {Hancock, John},
  month = sep,
  year = {2018},
  file = {/Users/BenjaminLee/Zotero/storage/LRIZZCAE/Lee - Squiggle a user-friendly two-dimensional DNA sequ.pdf}
}

@article{leePythonImplementationCodon2018,
  title = {Python {{Implementation}} of {{Codon Adaptation Index}}},
  volume = {3},
  issn = {2475-9066},
  doi = {10.21105/joss.00905},
  number = {30},
  journal = {Journal of Open Source Software},
  author = {Lee, Benjamin D.},
  month = oct,
  year = {2018},
  pages = {905},
  file = {/Users/BenjaminLee/Zotero/storage/V3MQVKZW/Lee - 2018 - Python Implementation of Codon Adaptation Index.pdf}
}
```

resume.cls:

```
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
% Medium Length Professional CV - RESUME CLASS FILE
%
% This template has been downloaded from:
% http://www.LaTeXTemplates.com
%
% This class file defines the structure and design of the template. 
%
% Original header:
% Copyright (C) 2010 by Trey Hunner
%
% Copying and distribution of this file, with or without modification,
% are permitted in any medium without royalty provided the copyright
% notice and this notice are preserved. This file is offered as-is,
% without any warranty.
%
% Created by Trey Hunner and modified by www.LaTeXTemplates.com
%
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
\ProvidesClass{resume}[2010/07/10 v0.9 Resume class]

\LoadClass[11pt,letterpaper]{article} % Font size and paper type

\usepackage[parfill]{parskip} % Remove paragraph indentation
\usepackage{array} % Required for boldface (\bf and \bfseries) tabular columns
\usepackage{ifthen} % Required for ifthenelse statements

\pagestyle{empty} % Suppress page numbers

\let\ori@document=\document

% Defines the rSection environment for the large sections within the CV
\newenvironment{rSection}[1]{ % 1 input argument - section name
  \sectionskip
  \MakeUppercase{\bf #1} % Section title
  \sectionlineskip
  \hrule % Horizontal line
  \begin{list}{}{ % List for each individual item in the section
    \setlength{\leftmargin}{1.5em} % Margin within the section
  }
  \item[]
}{
  \end{list}
}

% The below commands define the whitespace after certain things in the document - they can be \smallskip, \medskip or \bigskip
\def\namesize{\huge} % Size of the name at the top of the document
\def\addressskip{\smallskip} % The space between the two address (or phone/email) lines
\def\sectionlineskip{\medskip} % The space above the horizontal line for each section 
\def\nameskip{\bigskip} % The space after your name at the top
\def\sectionskip{\medskip} % The space after the heading section
```

cv4.tex:

```
\documentclass{resume} % Use the custom resume.cls style

\usepackage[left=0.75in,top=0.6in,right=0.75in,bottom=0.6in]{geometry} % Document margins
\usepackage{biblatex}
\addbibresource{blee.bib}

\begin{document}
\begin{rSection}{Publications}
\nocite{*}
\printbibliography[]
\end{rSection}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`rSection` is defined via a `list` environment. `\printbibliography` is also implemented as a list and when those lists are nested without breaking out of vertical mode that can lead to strange effects.

The easiest solution I could find was to issue `\leavevmode` before `\printbibliography`

```
\documentclass{resume} % Use the custom resume.cls style

\usepackage{biblatex}
\addbibresource{biblatex-examples.bib}

\begin{document}
\begin{rSection}{Publications}
\nocite{sigfridsson,worman,geer,nussbaum}
\leavevmode\printbibliography[heading=none]
\end{rSection}
\end{document}
```

[image: Bibliography with numeric labels in all positions as desired.]

Comment: @BenjaminLee Try `{\setlength{\parskip}{0pt}\leavevmode\printbibliography[heading=none]}`